# Yii::$app->session->getId() doesn't work in mongodb session component

Tags: php, mongodb, session, yii

`Yii::$app->session->getId()` returns an empty string.

How can I get the session id when I'm using the mongodb session component (`yii\mongodb\Session`)?

My config:

```
'session' => [
    'class' => 'yii\mongodb\Session',
    'writeCallback' => function($session)
        {
            return [
                'user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id,
                'agent' => Yii::$app->request->getUserAgent(),
                'ip' => Yii::$app->request->getUserIP(),
            ];
        }
]
```

Comment: do you mean session_id() ?

Comment: yes, but in Yii Framwork we can get session_id with Yii::$app->session->getId().

every thing is fine but when im using mongodb session component i get empty string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must open a session first.

```
Yii::$app->session->open();
return Yii::$app->session->id;
```